# XHTML still harmful?

Tags: xhtml

I'm starting a project where the client has mandated the use of XHTML 1.0 Strict. Now I'm wondering whether the problems described in [Sending XHTML as text/html Considered Harmful](http://www.hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml) are still current and whether I should try to convince the client that this (very strongly stated) requirement is counterproductive.

Does Internet explorer handle `application/xhtml+xml` correctly by now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE9 handles `application/xhtml+xml`, including SVG inside it, one of the main reasons to want to use this media type. (Otherwise, there's relatively little point in using it to date, as you get a bunch of scripting changes, and IE<9 incompatibility, in return for relatively little if any performance gain at the moment.)

I don't agree with Hixie that serving XHTML as `text/html` has *ever* been really harmful. Using the HTML-compatibility guidelines, XHTML poses no problems to any browsers since the ancient Netscape 4. Although it doesn't really get you anything on the client-side, it can be helpful to your own page handling workflow if you're working with XML processing tools. And the XML syntax rules, being stricter-but-simpler than HTML, are a good thing to author to; this gives the validator a chance to pick up on errors that are valid constructs in SGML/HTML but which are almost certainly not what you meant. (On the other hand, since the validator won't enforce HTML-compatibility guidelines there are a couple of places where it can let through well-formed-but-troublesome markup, most commonly self-closed `<script>` tags breaking the whole page.)

Specifically, to answer his points: `/>` and related SGML issues are only a problem to tools that really believe HTML is SGML—which is no browser ever, in the past. In the future, it is specifically allowed in non-XML HTML5.

Hiding scripts/stylesheets from ‘legacy’ (pre-HTML 3.2!) browsers hasn't been an issue for a decade or so: I came up with the mangled comment hack he (rightly) derides as ridiculous, but it was only an exercise; I never intended anyone to use it except in some strange hypothetical emergency. It's certainly not ‘necessary’ for using embedded scripts and stylesheets in XHTML-as-HTML... a straight `//<![CDATA[` hack is enough if you need to be able to include `<` and `&` characters, and more commonly you don't even need that.

No-one actually wants to sniff for XHTML-as-HTML and treat it differently, so that whole section is moot. “Sending XHTML 1.1 as text/html is NEVER fine” has been changed by W3C (it now is fine after all), and XHTML 2.0 is dead.

So yes, use XHTML 1.0 Strict, or XHTML 1.1 or XHTML5, if you like. But until IE9 is your baseline browser (and that's not going to be the case for *ages*), you'll have to stick with `text/html`.

Comment: The question of “Sending XHTML 1.1 as text/html is NEVER fine” is a right mess. The XHTML Working Group have published a note (which is informative, not normative and is "not endorsed by the W3C membership") which says it is OK, but nothing (as far as I know) has actually overridden the IETF RFC on the subject.

Comment: As I understand the W3C process, if one person writes a draft saying "I think x is a good idea" and there's insufficient support from others to back it, such proposals fail, and the draft is not deleted, but ends its life as a W3C Note. That seems, more or less, to be what happened in the case of the proposal to allow XHTML 1.1 to be served as text/html.

Comment: Yes, ‘right mess’ is right. In practice of course no client objects to XHTML 1.1 as `text/html`. The original prohibition against doing this was put in place to try to push the web onto `application/xhtml+xml` in time for the next, explicitly-HTML-incompatible version of XHTML. Of course in the real world, where IE didn't get updated for years and no-one at all wanted XHTML 2.0, this plan went awry.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer 9 will handle application/xhtml+xml documents <del>through a tag soup parser</del>.

Internet Explorer 8 and earlier will prompt the user to save the document or open it in another application.

Internet Explorer 6 and newer all have significant market share (although this does depend, to some degree, on your market).

Nothing significant has changed as regards browser support for real XHTML for many years.

It is still far more trouble than it is worth unless you actually use XML parsers in your production chain (in which case, good luck persuading them to output XHTML that meets the HTML Compatibility Guidelines).

Comment: Do you have a reference for your first statement? It seems to defeat the purpose of XHTML entirely.

Comment: IE9's `application/xhtml+xml` parser isn't really a tag soup parser. It will choke and die on XML well-formedness errors; the difference to other browsers is that it will display what it got of the page *so far* up to the error point, rather than replacing the whole page with an error message. It is a pity that (in current betas) no visual indication is given that the page was prematurely terminated, but it's a start.

Comment: I must have been misinformed. I haven't done too much research into it as it will be years before IE9 is the dominant version of IE, so there isn't any more point in looking at application/xhtml+xml for a long while. These days I'm sticking to HTML (although I'll still fix bugs in Catalyst::View::ContentNegotiation::XHTML if anyone reports them).

Comment: It's not really XML *parsers* that need to output HTML-compatible XHTML as it is XML *serialisers*. And it's really not *that* hard. I do it, and use content-negotiation to serve different content-types to different user-agents. A little programming skill is needed sure, but it probably didn't take me more than one evening to get right.

Comment: @Alohci: I think dual media types is a bit ambitious for most authors. There are tweaks to the CSS model and significant changes to the scripting and DOM models that will trip up the average clod decorating their page with third-party scripts and styles. Plus doing it with content negotiation means serving a `Vary` header, which causes big caching problems for IE. For most people, given the slim practical advantages of serving `application/xhtml+xml`, I'm not convinced it's worth it.

Comment: @bobince - I would agree with pretty much all of that. My comment was based on the premise that if someone really *wanted* to do it, how hard would it be. Actually however, I'm not familiar with the tweaks to the CSS model. Can you point me to a page that describes this?

Comment: The main thing is that `body background` no longer fills the viewport when the document is shorter than the viewport height. There's also selectors' case-sensitivity to worry about of course.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you mean by "Internet Explorer".

For instance, IE6 is still from something like 2001 (that hasn't changed), and no, it still doesn't handle it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Over the past one year, (27th May 2017 - 27th April 2018), the combined share of IE 6, 7, and 8 comprises 1.72% according to [netmarketshare](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?options=%7B%22filter%22%3A%7B%22%24and%22%3A%5B%7B%22deviceType%22%3A%7B%22%24in%22%3A%5B%22Desktop%2Flaptop%22%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D%2C%22dateLabel%22%3A%22Trend%22%2C%22attributes%22%3A%22share%22%2C%22group%22%3A%22browserVersion%22%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22share%22%3A-1%7D%2C%22id%22%3A%22browsersDesktopVersions%22%2C%22dateInterval%22%3A%22Monthly%22%2C%22dateStart%22%3A%222017-05%22%2C%22dateEnd%22%3A%222018-04%22%2C%22segments%22%3A%22-1000%22%2C%22pageLength%22%3A50%7D).

Every other major browser supports real XHTML (i.e. sent with the `application/xhtml+xml` MIME type. My answer to you is "No, it's not harmful".

Whether it's advantageous, I would guess it doesn't matter much until you actually grok and use XML technologies (SVG, MathML, etc) on the web comfortably (yes HTML syntax also supports them, but it's virtually a hack).

If browser makers put more effort into XML parsers, it could still matter for pure parsing speed.