# Serving your XHTML with the correct MIME type

Tags: php, html, xml, xhtml, mime-types

As long as I can remember, I've make a great effort to do things the proper way. Well, what I consider the proper way to be anyway.

Now I feel that it is time to get some very important questions answered once and for all.

All who swear to XHTML will, sooner or later, stumble upon the quote: "unless you serve the right MIME type, you document will be interpreted as regular HTML"

Say what? I've created a perfectly sound XHTML document, following all the standards and stuff. What have I done wrong? What have I missed?

As far as I understand it, it's a server thing for the most part, so of course I've investigated that too, and it would seem that the PHP function header() is the answer to the problem.

Yay, then all is good. Well no, in fact it's not, because no matter how much I search the net, I am simply unable to find consistent information about how to go about the problem and when I do find something remotely relevant, it's all about browser comparability and such.

Let it be said as clearly as possible.

I so not care about browser computability. (not at this point anyway)

All I really want is receive the XML type epic fail message if I've made a mistake and of course of course the knowledge about how I actually make this happen.

In short, I want to part with the SGML way and embrace the XML way, and I want to be able, without even the tiniest bit of doubt, to say that this document is valid XML/XHTML and is interpreted as such.

My thought is that I can simply require the XHTML document in question, via a PHP script, and send it of with a proper MIME type, but how it is actually done is still a mystery due to conflicting information on the net.

I do hope that someone will be able to supply the answer I'm looking for, preferably with links to the relevant information to back it up. If you can do this for me, I will be forever grateful.

Best regards.

Edit:
I can't say that I understand why or how, but at least I found a way to make it act as it should, simply by adding:
`<?php header("Content-type: application/xhtml+xml"); ?>`
to the top of a regular xhtml document, of course changing the filetype to PHP to actually make it run the script.

I'm quite sure that this is not the end of the story, but for now I'm happy.

Comment: *(related)* [What are the problems associated with serving pages with an xhtml content type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351380/xhtml-what-are-the-problems-associated-with-serving-pages-with-content-applica)

Comment: *(related)* [XHTML still harmful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368497/xhtml-still-harmful)

Comment: I am not sure there is a question in this.  You say you aren't worried about browser compatibility, but it is the browser the decides how to parse the document and what mime-types vary how it parses the document.  Also, it is generally up to the Web Server you are using to determine the mime-type of the data (unless you set the header manually, via PHP).

Comment: Setting the header via PHP is exactly what I want to do, if that is the right way to go about it that is.

Personally I think the question is pretty clear.

I've created an XHTML site, only to find that it is not treated as such by the various browser. Seemingly this is not actually a flaw with the browser in question, but with the document header, content type, mime type, whatever it's called.

So how do I fix this?

Comment: @Zacariaz no, it's not. Forcing the Content Type via header() would always serve the content as XHTML no matter what was requested. The right way to do it would be to inspect the Accept Header in the Request Header and then see if the resource can be represented like requested (Content Negotiation). If not, the server should respond with a Bad Request header.

Comment: Ok, I realise I may sound stupid, but let be make as clear as I can, because I don't understand a thing now.

I have a site, I made a big effort to make it in XHTML and made sure it validates. I'm then told that this doesn't matter, it still isn't XHTML. This of course makes no sense. All I want to do, regardless of the consequences, is to be able to say. Hey, I have an XHTML site. But seemingly no one can tell me how to do this.

Comment: @Zacariaz Well, it **is** XHTML. You *authored* it as such. It *validates* as such. But if you dont *serve* it as such a browser will not *interprete* it as such. You *can* force the Content Type via the `header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml')` and browsers that support it will interprete it as such. But not all do and you dont want to limit your audience just because of that. And it's not like you would get any notable benefits from serving it as XHTML. The web is broken anyway and with HTML5 being the next standard it will be a long time til that is fixed.

Comment: [Here's an interesting article on the issue.](http://www.schillmania.com/content/entries/2004/10/24/application-xhtml+xml/)

Comment: Just one of the many reasons the XHTML1.1 was obsoleted by HTML5.

Comment: @Rich - I think you're thinking of XHTML2. HTML5 will supersede XHTML1.1 and HTML 4.01 alike.

Comment: I guess what I was trying to say was that now XHTML2 doesn't exist, HTML5 is the sucessor to XHTML, and hence this issue isn't current. The questioner is wasting their time worrying about this issue, as things have moved on since then.

Comment: @Rich - Not really. HTML5 still allows use of both HTML and XML mime types to select either the HTML or XML parser in browsers, to process either the HTML or XHTML serializations of HTML5.

Comment: I didn't realise that they had kept the XML version – my mistake. Despite that, is there really any point using it? Browser support is low, and attributes like autoplay or checked are confusing in the XML serialisation. (autoplay='false' meaning the same as autoplay='true' if HTML for instance)

Comment: @Rich - autoplay="false" and autoplay="true" are invalid in both HTML and XHTML serializations of HTML5. The only difference between the serializations is that HTML permits autoplay on its own while the minimal form in XHTML is autoplay="". (Which is also valid for the HTML serialization)

Comment: Exactly, but it's confusing for beginners, as they might assume in XHTML those will work, whereas in HTML, autoplay on it's own is allowed and will validate. It doesn't make sense for HTML to follow XML rules in many edge cases, so serving it as text that looks a lot like XML is better than serving XML as XML IMO.

Comment: @Rich - as for whether there's any point in using it - sadly very little. All the cool things that you would be able to do in XHTML but not HTML, e.g. nested forms or forms that wrap `<tr>`s, are classified as invalid mark-up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you force the `/xhtml+xml` header, then IE won't interpret your pages anymore. Which is why nobody actually bothers to do it correctly. (And the very reason I do it on another site.)

It's however possible to let your webserver handle the sending of the correct MIME type. Normally you could let [mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html) handle that. However that requires having two versions of each document:

```
index.en.html
index.en.xhtml
```

Then if a url/resource `/index` is requested, it will automatically determine the appropriate document version, and send it with the right media type. However, it doesn't really understand the type variance of the serialization formats, nor can you set a precedence. And holding out two files with the same content is not overly senseible to begin with.

Therefore an easier approach would be to use mod_rewrite to handle the MIME type switching:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !application/xhtml\+xml
RewriteRule .+\.xhtml$ - [T=text/html]
```

This will send the configured header for all .xhtml documents, but override that if the browser does not indicate XHTML support. That's not quite complete, because to avoid proxy issues you also need to set the Vary: header if you manually do any kind of content negotation. This requires mod_header:

```
RewriteRule .+\.xhtml$ - [E=VARY_XHTML:1]
Header append Vary "Accept" env=VARY_XHTML
```

You can do the same with a PHP script wrapper, but then you lose all the benefits of having the server handle it. Either way, it's quite a bit of effort, which is why hardly anyone really does it. But if you really want the XML parsing errors, this might be a semi-workable option.

Comment: Of course I had to check first, before making such a bold statement, thus the late reply, but it would seem that IE9 do not suffer from this problem and if people can't be bothered to upgrade, they are probably not interested in what I have to say anyway, so problem solved. It would be nice though, to be able to inform people what they need to do in order to view my site, but I suppose that is still possible. In any case thanks for the answer.

Comment: of course IE9 don't actually treat it as XML/XHTML, but that I can live with.

Comment: @Zacariaz - IE9 will indeed treat it as XML/XHTML if you use an XML mime type. You won't get the yellow screen of death if the XML is not well-formed, but that's not an XML requirement. The only such requirement is that the XML parser must stop processing the input stream as XML if a well-formedness error occurs, and IE9 does that

Comment: As I understand it, the XML standard require the parser to fail and notify if it does not validate as XML. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Zacariaz - It's kind of hard to require in a parser spec that it must "notify" since there's no guarantee that that there is anything or anyone to notify, nor that there exists any means of doing so. It's certainly widely considered the right thing to do in browsers, and it's disappointing that IE9 doesn't do so.

Answer (score 3):

To get a browser parser to parse XHTML with an XML parser, it must be served with an [XML Mime Type](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/infrastructure.html#xml-mime-type)

HTML5 defines this as:

> The term XML MIME type is used to
>   refer to the MIME types text/xml,
>   application/xml, and any MIME type
>   whose subtype ends with the four
>   characters "+xml". [RFC3023]

The most common such mime type is `application/xhtml+xml`, but it is far from being the only possible one.

Comment: Interesting. So by using e.g. text/xml you could also trick IE into XHTML compliance? (found some `<?xml-stylesheet` workarounds for that)

Comment: @mario - IE, pre version 9, just doesn't interpret XHTML, and there's nothing that can be done about that. But it did have a XML parser, which would take an XML input and apply an xslt stylesheet to it. I believe that what it does is to take the output of *that*, and re-parse it as normal HTML.

Comment: That's what I thought. Such an [XSL stylesheet](http://www.echoofeden.com/digest/mit/2007/03/06/ie-xhtml-bug/) just converts any /xml document into HTML. So no actual XHTML parsing rules, nor XML DOM. But at least might accomplish what OP wanted: verify the xml-correctness before display.